# NodeJS - how to export a module correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given two modules `a` and `b`. I know that it is possible to expose `a`'s functionality to another module using the `module.exports`. I probably do not use it correctly.

**a.js**

```
function A() { ... }
A.prototype.func = function() { ... }

function test() {
    new A().func();
}

test();
module.exports = {
    A : new A()
};
```

The `test()` is working correctly. But the following breaks:

**b.js**

```
var A = require("./a");
A.func(); //throws an exception
```

How do I export the whole `A` module with its functionality?

**Update:** executing `console.log(A)` over `b` (as a second line), does not reveal any of `A`'s methods and variables.

Comment: As per your edit, if you want to see the keys on `A`, try `Object.keys(A)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
module.exports = new A();
```

You won't be able to instantiate a new `A` in b, but it seems like that's what you want.

**Edit:**

Or you could change `b.js` to:

```
var A = require('./a');
A.A.func();
```

But this is likely not what you want.

The idea is that whatever `exports` is will be what is returned from `require`. It's exactly the same reference.

Comment: You exported an object with a property called `A` set to the instance.

Comment: firstly thank you. secondly, do you have any clue why i cannot access `A.obj` within module `b` when i have set in module `a` the following: `A.obj = { key : "value"};`?

Comment: Yes. `obj` is attached to the function `A`, not the instance returned via `new A()`. Using new creates an object from its prototype and calls the constructor, nothing more. If you want access to things attached to the function `A`, you'll have to return that and instantiate it in b.